# Use of shl and rol in assembly input and output

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am writing assembly code to accept n numbers from users to perform addition.
Why shl and rol instructions are used while taking input and displaying output?

Code:

```
takeno:
print msg2,len2 ;calls a macro to display "Enter number"
accept var2,17    ;accepts number in var2
xor rbx,rbx
mov rsi,var2      ;how rsi works as array or array pointer?
mov ch,16
mov cl,4

up:
shl rbx,cl        ;Why this step ?
mov al,[rsi]
call asciitohex   ;convers ascii input to hex
add bl,al
inc rsi
dec ch
jnz up

add [var3],rbx
dec byte[var1]
jnz takeno

xor rbx,rbx
mov rbx,[var3]
mov rsi,var2
mov ch,16
mov cl,4

display:
rol rbx,cl          ;why rol?
mov al,bl
and al,0f           ;what this line does?
call asciitohex
mov [rsi],al
inc rsi
dec ch
jnz display
```

Comment: I don't know... Why are you using `rol`? Is this a test? You're telling us that it's your code.

Comment: shifting by 4 (in cl) bits shifts plus and'ing by 0x0F returns the upper nibble of bl. e.g. if BL=a3, afterwards it's a, so you can hexconvert it to the upper half of the hexvalue you want to display

Comment: @Tommylee2k shl rbx,cl can work instead of rol rbx,cl?

Comment: if you just need the value in bl, it doesnt matter which shift-left operation you use. ROL has the advantage, that you get your original value back after 16 "rol rbx.4" ... that way you can display all 16 nibbles of rBX without reading it again, in one loop (like it's done here: ch is loaded with 16 + dec ch + jnz )

Comment: How does `asciitohex` make sense as a function name?  Its doesn't convert ASCII to hex.  I'm guessing it maps a 4-bit integer to `'0'-'9'` or `'A'-'F'` as appropriate.  I'd maybe call it `nibbletohexascii` or something.  Or did you call the wrong function in `display`?

Comment: if the code above works as intended, asciitohex must to both, convert 0-15 to '0'-'9','a'-'f' **and back**. both encode and decode rbx use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
display:
rol rbx,cl          ;why rol?
mov al,bl
and al,0f           ;what this line does?
call asciitohex
mov [rsi],al
inc rsi
dec ch
jnz display
```

this is a function to display the content of RBX as 16 digits of hex

 the first rolls the upper 4 bits leftwise, so that they appear as lowest nibble, afterwards they're "masked out" with 0x0f, to just keep this one nibble. I assume that "asciitohex" makes 0-15 to '0'-'9','a'-'f', which is then stored in [SI]
this is repeated 16 times, ( ROL keeps all the data in rBX, just rearranges them. --> all 16 digits are stored in [SI]-[SI+15]

```
ROL sample: ROL rBX 
RBX before ROL       AEFD12349876CCDE
    after  ROL,4     EFD12349876CCDEA  (a gets last nibble)
           and 0x0f  000000000000000A --> first Digit
    after  ROL,4     FD12349876CCDEAE  (a gets last nibble)
           and 0x0f  000000000000000E --> second Digit
    after  ROL,4     D12349876CCDEAEF  (a gets last nibble)
           and 0x0f  000000000000000F --> 3rd Digit
```

and so on

the upper function is the other way round, it converts the hexString at [SI] to a 64bit int in register BX
BX is zeroed, and for each digit the current value is SHL'ed by one nibble, then the bin value of the current digit in [SI] is added to it

```
xor rbx,rbx
mov rsi,var2      ;how rsi works as array or array pointer?
mov ch,16
mov cl,4

up:
shl rbx,cl        ;Why this step ?
mov al,[rsi]
call asciitohex   ;convers ascii input to hex
add bl,al
inc rsi
dec ch
jnz up
```

also here, an example tells more than a ton of explaining:

```
SI content "ac12...."
rBX=0000000000000000
                   SHL rBX,4 0000000000000000
"a" is added (after convert) 000000000000000a
                   SHL rBX,4 00000000000000a0
"c" is added (after convert) 00000000000000ac
                   SHL rBX,4 0000000000000ac0
"1" is added (after convert) 0000000000000ac1
                   SHL rBX,4 000000000000ac10
"2" is added (after convert) 000000000000ac12
...
16 times for completely fill rBX
```

Comment: @Deadpool: using `rol rbx, cl` when cl is always 4 is totally braindead compared to using `rol rbx, 4`.   `rol r,cl` is a 3-uop instruction on Intel CPUs, with 2 cycle latency, while `rol r,imm8` is a 1 uop instruction with 1 cycle latency.  The imm8 form is one byte longer, but `mov cl, 4` is two bytes, so it's just totally dumb.  It's not even more readable: using `cl` implies that the count can vary.  It also puts the `4` farther away in the source code from the `0x0f` mask that it goes with.

Comment: I agree, the algorithm is a good one, the implementation "can be optimized" (friendly speaking). e.g. the "read rbx" function doesnt check for a length, it's always 16 digits read. on the other hand, "write rbx" always output 16 digits, even if there's 15 trailing zeros (probably that's wanted, i'm not sure of that)